# Почему не отрабатывает transition в обратную сторону?

Tags: css, scss

**Код:**

```
.outside {
    background: url("../img/shutterstock_336992036.jpg") no-repeat scroll center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 921px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    .outside_hover {
       transition:background 0.8s;
       display: none;
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
        &:hover .outside_hover {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none repeat  scroll 0 0;
            @include size(100%, 921px);
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```

По идее, при  наведении  на `.outside` всплывает блок `.outside_hover` и в течении `0.8s` появляется `background`.

**На деле** так, но как только я увожу курсор `background` пропадает не плавно, а сразу же исчезает.

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что когда курсор уходит, то сразу же срабатывает свойство `display: none` - блок сразу же пропадает и нельзя увидеть, что с ним происходит.

Рекомендую использовать не `display:none` для включение/выключения блока, а, например, `opacity:0` или `visibility:hidden`: во-первых, появится возможность лучше управлять анимацией, во-вторых, браузеру не придётся перерисовывать страницу, что снизит нагрузку, ибо свойство `display:none` не просто прячет элемент, а удаляет из DOM и переформировывает контент всей страницы.

Больше информации по ссылке: [display](https://webref.ru/css/display)

Comment: Это то, что было нужно. Спасибо большое!